# Rounding large exponential numbers e.g. (6.624147...e+25 to 6.62e+25)

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I have a list of very large numbers I need to round. 
For example:

`6.624147027484989e+25` I need to round to `6.62e25`.

However, `np.around`, `math.ceiling`, `round()`, etc... are not working. I'm thinking because instead of round `6.624147027484989e+25` to `6.62e25`, it's just making it an integer while I actually need to make the entire number much smaller... if that makes sense.

Comment: your number is an `int` so round doesn't make sense here, do you mean to format the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, if I understand your problem correctly, you could use `float("%.2e" % x)`

This just converts the value to text, in exponential format, with two fractional places (so 'pi' would become `"3.14e+00"`), and then converts that back to float. It will work with your example, and with small numbers like `5.42242344e-30`

For python 3.6+, it's better to use `float(f"{x:.2e}")` - thanks @gabriel-jablonski

Comment: Since f-strings are usually the preferred method for python3.6+, I'd recommend using `float(f"{x:.2e}")` instead.

Comment: This does work!  Thank you! The only problem is that it doesn't work for a list of numbers and it's tricky because my list is actually a list of lists.

Comment: for a list you can use `newlist =  [  float(f"{x:.2e}") for x in oldlist ]`  and for a list of list,  `newlist =  [  [ float(f"{x:.2e}") for x in lst] for lst in oldlist ]`

Answer (score 1):

- you can use python string format to round of.

```py
i = 6.624147027484989e+25
new_i = float('{:0.2e}'.format(i))
print(new_i)
```

output:

> 6.62e+25

Reference on more string formating: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to change the number but retain the type (currently all other answers are converting this to a string) or a numpy array of types you could do something like,

```
$ ipython
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: num = 6.624147027484989e+25

In [3]: np.around(num, decimals=-24)
Out[3]: 6.6e+25

In [4]: np.around(num, decimals=-23)
Out[4]: 6.619999999999999e+25
```

Though now you have to worry about numerical precision.